# Laravel join same table for 2 columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join

I do currently have this code:

```
        return Datatable::query($query = DB::table('acquisitions')
            ->where('acquisitions.deleted_at', '=', null)
            ->where('acquisitions.status', '!=', 2)
            ->join('contacts', 'acquisitions.contact_id', '=', 'contacts.id')
            ->join('user', 'acquisitions.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
            ->select('contacts.*', 'acquisitions.*', 'acquisitions.id as acquisitions_id', 'user.first_name as supervisor_first_name', 'user.last_name as supervisor_last_name', 'user.id as user_id'))
```

The data from the user table is used for 2 columns: `acquisitions.supervisor_id` and `acquisitions.user_id`. I need the `first_name` and the `last_name` for both of this tables, the above query does however currently only use the `id` from the `acquisitions.user_id` field. I also tried to use a table alias, that does also not work, I assume that I'm doing something wrong here.

So in short: I also need that the query selects the data for the user, based on the id from the `acquisitions.supervisor_id` and makes it available as `supervisor_first_name` and `supervisor_last_name`.

Comment: Have you tried using DB::raw() within the select statement.

Comment: No, I'm a bit clueless how ti implement it into the query, would appreciate if you could help me out with that. Nortmally I'd just do it with eloquent, unfortunately that is not possible here due to a plugin. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to your next to last comment on the other answer, you need a self join per reference table. Try this:

```
$result = DB::select('SELECT
u.name user_first_name,
u.last_name user_last_name,
u.email user_email,
s.name supervisor_name,
s.last_name supervisor_last_name,
s.email supervisor_email
FROM acquisitions a
JOIN users u ON a.user_id = u.id
JOIN users s ON a.supervisor_id = s.id');

return $result;
```

Note that `$result` is an array of `StdClass` objects, not a Collection, but you can still iterate it and call the current item's values:

```
foreach ($result as $item) {
    print($item->supervisor_first_name);
}
```

If you need a `WHERE` clause, e.g. to get a specific user's row from `acquisitions`, you would do that by adding a parameter to the query like so:

```
$result = DB::select('SELECT
u.name user_first_name,
u.last_name user_last_name,
u.email user_email,
s.name supervisor_name,
s.last_name supervisor_last_name,
s.email supervisor_email
FROM acquisitions a
JOIN users u ON a.user_id = u.id
JOIN users s ON a.supervisor_id = s.id
WHERE a.user_id = ?
', [3]);
```

**EDIT**

If you need the resultset to be a `Collection`, you can easily convert the array to one, using the `hydrate` method:

```
$userdata = \App\User::hydrate($result); // $userdata is now a collection of models
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, sadly I do now have the issue that the package won't work with it as it appears to be requiring a collection `__clone method called on non-object `

Comment: Make sure you're actually getting valid results, and please see my edit

Comment: The query actually works, but does not return exactly what I need. Now I only get the data I specified below (in the comment) but is missing all the other values from the acquisitions table. Regarding the converting to a collection, does that still work if the data is not from a specific table? I never used that function, I mean in this case the datasets should actually be from the acquisitions table and just include the data that the current query (that you created above) is outputting, I hope you know what I mean, I'm quite tired already. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: TBH I haven't used `hydrate` much, but since it's a method of the Eloquent model I would imagine it "prefers" to have data from a single table and possibly its relationships as well. In any case, you have to test which works better for you. As for the "other" data you need from acquisitions, just append it in the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: How can you do this is Eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like;

```
return Datatable::query($query = DB::table('acquisitions')
    ->where('acquisitions.deleted_at', '=', null)
    ->where('acquisitions.status', '!=', 2)
    ->join('contacts', 'acquisitions.contact_id', '=', 'contacts.id')
    ->join('user', 'acquisitions.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
            ->select( \DB::raw("  contacts.*, acquisitions.*, acquisitions.id as acquisitions_id, user.first_name as supervisor_first_name, user.last_name as supervisor_last_name, user.id as user_id   ") )
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not help me. I know how to use a Raw query inside the select, I however still don't know how the proper query would have to look to assign the values correctly :/

Comment: Besides the fact that I'm quite sure that I would need to adjust the join first.

Comment: You cannot use aliases in the query, if that is what you are trying to achieve. What you can do is do a sub query, and use the output in the where statement. Can you provide more details on the issue, as I do not quite understand the exact problem.

Comment: I have 2 tables. `user` and `acquisitions`. The table `acquisitions`contains 2 columns: `user_id` and `supervisor_id`. `user` contains `first_name` and `last_name`. Now I want to select the first and last name for both the supervisor_id and the user_id as supervisor_first_name, supervisor_last_name, user_first_name, user_first_name

Answer (score 0):

```
$devices = DB::table('devices as d')
->leftJoin('users as au', 'd.assigned_user_id', '=', 'au.id')
->leftJoin('users as cu', 'd.completed_by_user_id', '=', 'cu.id')
->select('d.id','au.name as assigned_user_name','cu.name as completed_by_user_name');
```

Also follow this link

https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/161